# Multidimensional ARRAY With NULL element inside inner ARRAY

Tags: python, postgresql, multidimensional-array, sqlalchemy

So, I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id_doc integer not null,
    multi  timestamp without time zone[]
);
```

The 'multi' column is supposed to represent data similar to this JSON array:

```
[
    ['2017-02-03T17:20:00', '2017-02-03T17:20:01'],
    ['2017-02-01T16:21:55', '2017-02-02T13:23:03'],
]
```

It works fine, except when one of the inner arrays is empty.
When I try to insert:

```
INSERT INTO test (id_doc, multi)
    VALUES (1, ARRAY[ARRAY[NULL], ARRAY['2017-02-03T17:01:30'::timestamp]]);
```

Postgres (9.3) gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  ARRAY could not convert type timestamp without time zone[] to text[]
LINE 2: VALUES (1, ARRAY[ARRAY[NULL], ARRAY['2017-03-02T16:53:00'::t...
                                      ^
```

Even though the error points to the second element (ARRAY['2017-02-03T17:01:30'::timestamp]), the problem seems to be rooted on the first (ARRAY[NULL]) because I can get it to work if I change the INSERT statement to:

```
INSERT INTO test (id_doc, multi)
    VALUES (1, ARRAY[ARRAY[NULL::timestamp], ARRAY['2017-02-03T17:01:30'::timestamp]]);
```

Unfortunately, I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM (Python) and I can't seem to find a way to force SQLAlchemy to append the casting suffix to NULL fields (::timestamp). Not using SQLAlchemy is not an option right now.

This seems to happen only to timestamp multidimensional arrays. If 'multi' is of type text[], for example, I can insert rows with NULL elements in the inner array just fine (without the casting suffix).

I don't understand why Postgres complains about the NULL element.

So, does anyone know of a way to either:

1. force SQLAlchemy ORM to cast NULL/None fields to timestamps; or
2. make Postgres understand that that NULL is a timestamp without the added ::timestamp? (maybe a constraint or function?)

One more thing: you should probably know that the table is actually auto-generated. We have a system that takes JSON schema(s) and automatically creates relational tables (supports only PostgreSQL for now).

We **do** have control over how this system does that, so if we **absolutely** need to change how it represents multidimensional arrays in a Postgres DB, we can. But we'd rather not.

As it is, it works great for all kinds of columns/fields except this one edge case with empty arrays of timestamp (multidimensional only, one-dimensional works fine). And changing that might break compatibility with a lot of our apps running on top of this.

Any help or comment is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you should show the Python code where sqlalchemy is told to make its magic

Comment: There are several alternatives: `array[null]::timestamp[]` or `'{null}'::timestamp[]`

Comment: You can insert/update data via functions or create view on `test` table with `multi text[][]` and create triggers for cast text[][] to  timestamp[][] on insert/update

Comment: can you provide a full MCVE please?   see https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3916/not-possible-to-insert-nulls-in-postgresql#comment-34464902 for an example of a proper MCVE.